# Can Do While Loop stop when counter reaches X

Tags: asp-classic, while-loop

I want to edit some legacy code written in classic-ASP.

Currently I've got a subroutine declared that uses a for-next loop to output some radio buttons:

```
 For i = 1 to Cols
   response.write "blah"
   ...
 Next
```

**i** is simply a counter, **Cols** is a value passed to the sub-routine. I tried editing the for-loop to be a while loop instead:

```
i = Start
do while i <= Cols
  response.write "blah"
  ...
  i = i + 1
loop
```

But I get a Response Buffer Limit Exceeded error. If I replace Cols with the value it works fine. Is this a limitation in classic-ASP?

---

Reason I want to use a do while loop is because currently the sub-routine is limited to looping from 1 to *Cols*. It would be helpful to sometimes specify the loop counts backwards (i.e. step -1) but I can't write:

```
if Direction = Backwards then 
  For i = Cols to 1 step -1
else
  For i = 1 to Cols
end if
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
If Direction = Backwards Then
    cs = 10
    ce = 1
    s = -1
Else
    cs = 1
    ce = 10
    s = 1
End If

For i = cs To ce Step s
    ''
Next
```

Comment: That works! I did not realise you could "step X" and leave X as a variable. Thanks.